# how to make an input dissapear?

Tags: python, string, passwords

i want to make hangman for two players. Player 1 can give a word in that player 2 will guess. But i want that the word that player 1 gives dissapears for that player 2 actually can guess the letters without already knowing the word.

Can someone help me plz?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that it's always good to add more details to your question, plus what you've tried so far with code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like writing without showing the word? Use `getpass` from standard library:

```py
>>> import getpass
>>> word = getpass.getpass(prompt='Word: ', stream=None) 
Word: 
>>> word
'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it to variable

```
var = input()
```

or use module getpass to make the input invisible even when writting